# Asp.Net MVC routing using C# key words in route

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I want to create a route that uses params as part of the URL.

The problem I am having is when I create the default, I cannot use params as its a reserved c# word.

Wondering if there is a way around this. (see the use of params in route and when used as the default I get a compiler error: Expression expected)

Here is sample code:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{db}/{proc}/{params}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Data", action = "Index", db = UrlParameter.Optional, proc = UrlParameter.Optional, params = UrlParameter.Optional}
        );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use C# keywords by prepending @ symbol to them, as MSDN suggests.
In your case, use `@params` instead of `params`.

[To quote MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx)

> Keywords are predefined, reserved identifiers that have special meanings to the compiler. They cannot be used as identifiers in your program unless they include @ as a prefix. For example, @if is a valid identifier but if is not because if is a keyword.

Is there any particular reason you need this variable to be called `params`?

Comment: routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{db}/{proc}/{params}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Data", action = "Index", db = UrlParameter.Optional, proc = UrlParameter.Optional, @params = UrlParameter.Optional}
            );

Comment: Strange, I've tried it and failed. I must have made a typo. Thanks for response. I updated my answer accordingly.